# Selenium IEWebdriver(32 bit) performance issue when using IE9 (32 bit) on windows7 (64 bit) through VS2010

Tags: internet-explorer-9, selenium-webdriver

We create all of our tests for FF, Chrome and IE9 in VS2010R2 using Selenium2 and C#. We use one common code base for all test just point different browsers to run through it. To run the tests we use VS2010 Test Agent/Build environment. So it will kick off a test run of n number of tests to the build server that then passes the tests off to the agent to run the test.

Both the Chrome and FF tests run perfectly, but the IE9 tests are ***painfully*** slow (and usually timeout) but the test is exactly the same for each browser.

Just to give you a frame of reference here are the timings:

- Chrome test: 0:34.753 seconds
- Firefox test: 1:01:570 minute
- IE test: 14:26:54 minutes

We are running the 32 bit version of all the webdrivers and the test agent is 64 bit windows7.

From what I've read I don't want to switch to the 64 bit version as it contains an old JS handling engine.

I've been searching for weeks (off and on) for a resolution to this issue, but my google-fu wasn't strong enough. Any having or seen this issue?

Comment: We also went through a lot of effort to remove almost all of the xpath from out code to.